# Fourier transform and the Sobolev space $H_k$ in Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

The following is an excerpt from Folland's Real Analysis:

[image]

Would anybody elaborate why the estimate in the first box implies the second and third boxes?

Comment: what is the Fourier transform of $\partial^\alpha f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user1952009's comment, the first box itself does not imply the later two boxes. One would have the conclusions by looking at the Fourier transform of $\partial^\alpha f$ and applying the Plancherel Theorem.